# Bluetooth pairing in iOS: how to create custom pairing dialog?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, pairing

When connecting to a device which uses a passkey pairing method in iOS, the OS brings up a pairing dialog if necessary.  I have seen a couple of apps which use a custom dialog instead.  I think they show that before connecting to the device, and then somehow use the passkey that was entered when connecting to the device to bypass the OS dialog.

How can I use a custom dialog for pairing?

Alternately, if I know the passkey (in code), how can I avoid showing a pairing dialog completely?

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @hariszaman No, sorry, I don't know how to do it.  Let me know if you find a way

Comment: @AlexI did you find out if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question, I did a really long research and sadly the pairing process is completely controlled by iOS. There is no parameter we could change.